# get title of video

Tags: jquery, html, jsonp

Im using this [Script](http://jsfiddle.net/bmChE/)

If you type something you will see thumbnail of videos. I'm trying to show the title/span or any other info but with no luck. I have no idea of what I m doing wrong since all css elements can be found in the js script. So it should be very simple, but it just doesn't work/show. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward: http://jsfiddle.net/bmChE/3/

Look at the `videoResults()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spend all morning on this:)